# VB.Net Web Api Action not invoked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I have vb.net web api controller that I am trying to invoke but I'm getting back the following:

```
 {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:26944/api/employee/GetPerson/'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Employee' that matches the request."}
```

This is the web controller:

```
Public Class EmployeeController
    Inherits ApiController
    Private ReadOnly dbContext As MyEntities

    Sub New()
        Me.dbContext = New MyEntities
    End Sub

    <HttpGet>
    <ActionName("GetPerson")>
    Function Person(ByVal missionaryId As Integer) As IPRS_Data.getPersInfoDetail_Result
        Return Me.dbContext.getPersInfoDetail(missionaryId).First
    End Function

End Class
```

WebApiConfig:

```
Public Shared Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
    ' Web API configuration and services

    ' Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:="DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    )
    Dim xmlFormat = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(Function(t) t.MediaType = "application/xml")
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(xmlFormat)
End Sub
```

I'm invoking the service using: appbase/api/employee/GetPerson/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is decorated with HTTPGET and Actionname attribute. You don't need that if you have your method name starting with "Get" (like GetPerson). However, the Actionname is obsolete as it is not considered in your actual routing. Your routing is `"api/{controller}/{id}"`. If you want your action name being considered you need to modify your routing to `"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`. And if you want to have your id-param being considered per default routing you should rename the param in your method from `missionaryId` to just `id`.

```
Function Person(ByVal id As Integer) As IPRS_Data.getPersInfoDetail_Result
    Return Me.dbContext.getPersInfoDetail(id).First
End Function
```

And that's the way how to invoke it (don't forget to pass an Id because there is no other "GET" method in your controller which works paramless.

```
appbase/api/employee/15
```

or

```
appbase/api/employee?id=15
```

and if you insist on missionaryId

```
appbase/api/employee?missionaryId=15
```